Multiple of the same item components in item.json
I am working on making an emerald sword (because why not), I am almost done, except looking at the item.json, I find that there is components:{minecraft:enchantable{Data}} where Data is whatever id and slot the item can have. I only have one where it can have looting. Can I have one for mending, unbreaking,etc.?

I mean… if you can have looting, I don’t know why not?
